# Dynamic Combobox at SelectedIndex of ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, margin, selectedindex

In WPF application, I have a ListBox and binded with data from Sql. and also have a stackpanel inthe listbox.

once i double click the item of the Listbox, Where i need to place/add a dynamic combobox.

I can get the selected index of a ListBox.

```
int seleteditem = lstbxusername.SelectedIndex;
```

and i created dynamic Combobox

```
  System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox cmb = new ComboBox();
            cmb.Background = Brushes.Green;
```

Using Stackpanel to add a combobox

```
        newstckpnl.Children.Add(cmb);
```

My question is how to add a dynamic combobox  in the selected index of a listbox.

Is this possible or not?Helps appreciated.

Comment: Please read about MVVM. If you set `ItemsSource` via binding you shouldn't add items manually to `Items` collection of an `ItemsControl` (`ListBox` in your case) in code behind. You need bind `ItemsSource` to `ObservableCollection<string>` and add strings to this collection in view model.

Comment: Also, what do you bind `ItemsSource` to?

Comment: _I get margin={0,0,0,0}_ And what is wrong with it? You could get an answer much time ago if you describe your problem better. At now you force people to ask a lot of questions to make your issue clear.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can. You just need to get the `ListBoxItem` out of the `ListBox` first, as can be seen below.

```
var listBox = new ListBox();
var listBoxItem = listBox.SelectedItem as ListBoxItem;
var listBoxItemMargin = listBoxItem.Margin;
```

Currently you're adding strings to your `ListBox`. Strings obviously don't have margins. In order for the code above to work, you will need to add `ListBoxItems` to your `ListBox` as below.

```
listBox.Items.Add(new ListBoxItem {Content = dr.GetString(1) });
```

Comment: `var listBoxItem = listBox.SelectedItem as ListBoxItem;` in this area i get the null value. it doesn't get the seleteditem

Comment: `SelectedItem` represents item view model in case `ItemsSource` is used to populate `ListBox`. You must use `ItemContainerGenerator` of `ListBox` to get container for item and then take its `Margin`.

Comment: @User6667769 Could you show us how you're adding your items to the `Listbox`. That way I can see why this might be causing you an issue.

Comment: @User6667769 What do you mean _but how can i set it to the particular variabe_? Your question about how to get the margin of a selected item in `ListBox`. If you know how to get item container you know how to get its `Margin`.

Comment: `lstbxusername.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(selectedindex);` from here i can get the all the properties of the selected item. but the Margin of a selected item show {0,0,0,0}. @Maxim

Comment: @User6667769 and what is wrong with it? It shouldn't be zero? Why you decided that it should be non-zero? Please update your question providing more details.

Answer (score 0):

i did some thing , its worked for me!!

I get the selected index of a listbox

```
int seleteditem = lstbxusername.SelectedIndex;
```

Then created combobox

```
System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox cmb = new ComboBox();
```

By using combobox object , i added it in listbox selected index

```
 lstbxusername.Items.Insert(seleteditem, cmb);
```